# NSTableView example of use

Tags: objective-c, macos, nstableview

I have to write a little OSX app which make use of an NSTableView, but I didn't find a very good example of it, I would like have this result:
Someone could help me?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is a good NSTableview tutorial with bindings
[Phonebook/NSTableView Tutorial for Dummies](http://andrehoffmann.wordpress.com/2009/09/03/phonebook-tutorial-for-dummiesxcode-3-1-3/)

Answer (score 2):

The NSTableViewBinding sample project should be a good start http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/NSTableViewBinding/Introduction/Intro.html